# C# .net Core rounded corners for image

Tags: c#, .net-core

I save images from social networks and I want to do rounded corners for image and save it to the database. For example, I got a photo from the facebook by [url](https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1301054343328635&height=200&width=200&ext=1543247645&hash=AeQsBKhL3vAEVEBU) on my Api and I want to process this image

How it possible on .net Core

Below, what results I expect

Image before:

[image]

Image after:

[image]

Comment: This kind of processign requires a understanding of layers and transperency from you. Basically the entire image except for the circle in the mdidle is overriden with "transparent".

Comment: This might give you ideas about some of the image processing packages available for .NET Core: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **SixLabors.ImageSharp** library, it is available for .NET Core:

> PM > Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp

Here is the sample code:

```
public static void ApplyRoundedCorners(Image<Rgba32> img, float cornerRadius)
{
    IPathCollection corners = BuildCorners(img.Width, img.Height, cornerRadius);
    var graphicOptions = new GraphicsOptions(true) { BlenderMode = PixelBlenderMode.Src };
    img.Mutate(x => x.Fill(graphicOptions, Rgba32.Transparent, corners));
}

public static IPathCollection BuildCorners(int imageWidth, int imageHeight, float cornerRadius)
{
    var rect = new RectangularPolygon(-0.5f, -0.5f, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);

    IPath cornerToptLeft = rect.Clip(new EllipsePolygon(cornerRadius - 0.5f, cornerRadius - 0.5f, cornerRadius));

    var center = new Vector2(imageWidth / 2F, imageHeight / 2F);

    float rightPos = imageWidth - cornerToptLeft.Bounds.Width + 1;
    float bottomPos = imageHeight - cornerToptLeft.Bounds.Height + 1;

    IPath cornerTopRight = cornerToptLeft.RotateDegree(90).Translate(rightPos, 0);
    IPath cornerBottomLeft = cornerToptLeft.RotateDegree(-90).Translate(0, bottomPos);
    IPath cornerBottomRight = cornerToptLeft.RotateDegree(180).Translate(rightPos, bottomPos);

    return new PathCollection(cornerToptLeft, cornerBottomLeft, cornerTopRight, cornerBottomRight);
}

private static IImageProcessingContext<Rgba32> ConvertToAvatar(this IImageProcessingContext<Rgba32> processingContext, Size size, float cornerRadius)
{
    return processingContext.Resize(new ResizeOptions
    {
        Size = size,
        Mode = ResizeMode.Crop
    }).Apply(i => ApplyRoundedCorners(i, cornerRadius));
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
 using (var img = Image.Load("fb.jpg"))
 {
     using (Image<Rgba32> destRound = img.Clone(x => x.ConvertToAvatar(new Size(200, 200), 100)))
     {
         destRound.Save("output/fb-round.png");
     }
 }
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/SixLabors/Samples/tree/master/ImageSharp).

Comment: Package SixLabors.ImageSharp only beta version?

Comment: @IgorCova unfortunatelly it is, but was using it for a while and it is pretty stable.